# I want to display text when I move mouse over image in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to display text when I move mouse over image in JavaScript. I don't know where I am going as I am new to this.There is a table which has images I want to display its content when I move mouse over image . I want to use JavaScript here.

```
<script>
function show()
{
var welcome = document.getElementById('sub1');
welcome.style.display = 'block';
}

function hide()
{
 var welcome = document.getElementById('sub1');
 welcome.style.display = 'none';
}   
</script>

<div id="sub1" onmouseover="show();" onmouseout="hide();"> </div>

 //This is the image where I want to display a text.
<td><img border="0" src="images/img1.jpg"
alt="iphone 5s" width="304" height="228"></td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to replace the text with image or place text somewhere else ?
From my understanding , please check below code :

```
    <script>
function showText(text){
    document.getElementById("text").innerHTML=text;
}
function hide(){
    document.getElementById("text").innerHTML="";
}
</script>
<img src="image.jpg" id="image" onMouseOver="showText('Some Text')" onMouseOut="hide();">
<div id="text"></div>
```

Comment: I just want to display text on top of image .Probably a brief description of an image.

Comment: You can place the Div above the image . Then it will appear above the image. If the text and image is pulled from database and need to show the different text for each image, need to modify the above code . But the logic is same .

Comment: Thanks its working . Is there any way I can move the text ? Its displaying at the top . I want it on the image though or next to image .

Comment: You can place the text anywhere . Using a position absolute style applied for the DIV , you cn make the Div to appear on top of th image, so that text too. Those arrangement has to be done using HTML and CSS .

Comment: Got it Just made the change .Working! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use only css instead of using javascript: [codepen: display text  when I hover - css](http://codepen.io/yamitrvg12/pen/qZWQEL)

HTML

```
<div class="thumb-item">
  <img class="thumb-item__image" src="http://clapat.ro/themes/legrand-wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/2.jpg" alt="">
  <div class="thumb-item__info">
    <h5>Title here</h5>
    <p>This Is a caption Line</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.thumb-item {
  width: 400px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.thumb-item__image {
  width: 100%;
}
.thumb-item__info {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -30px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}
.thumb-item__info h5 {
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: tahoma;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.thumb-item__info p {
  font-size: 12px;
  margin: 4px 0 14px;
}
.thumb-item:hover .thumb-item__info {
  opacity: 1;
  bottom: -5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To write any text on your image or even add icons or something like that you have to create a div before your image tag ,, Often it's called a layout div.

```
<td><div class="layout"></div><img id="testImg" src="Your img path"></td>
```

Notice : We closed the div before put the image tag.
your css will be :

```
background:rgba(7,7,7,0.2);
position:absolute;
top:0;
bottom:0;
right:0;
left:0;
display:none
```

Change the background color and opacity as you like ..
jQuery Code :

```
$("#testImg").click(function () {
    $(".layout").css("display", "block");
    $(".layout").text('Test Paragraph');
```

});

Comment: I want to do it in JavaScript . Thanks for jquery code

Comment: Oh srry I haven't noticed that well , Sorry again for that mistake . do the same css and html but with javascript you can write inline the img tag onclick="showText()" .. Moving to js : you will create a function with that name and inside it you will write  document.getElementByClassName('layout').style.display="block"; so that you have make it appears , then put the text : document.getElementByClassName('layout').innerHTML('Your text');

Answer (score 0):

You are fairly close. I think the issue right now with your code is that your div that has the "onmouseover" and "onmouseout" is really small because it does not have anything in it.  Also, some browsers won't react to this event being created inline like you have it. Also, block styling can have some style issues in some browsers.  You might not want this but are instead just trying to take away the "none" on display.  I would also point you to JQuery if you can, but since you haven't mentioned JQuery, the following would work.  Here it is in JSFiddle as well for you to see:

https://jsfiddle.net/nkxjphjm/1/

```
<script>
function show() {
  var welcome = document.getElementById('sub1');
  welcome.style.display = '';
}

function hide() {
  var welcome = document.getElementById('sub1');
  welcome.style.display = 'none';
}
function init() {
  var surround = document.getElementById('surroundDiv');
  surround.onmouseover = show;
  surround.onmouseout=hide;  
}

window.onload = init;   
</script>

<div id="surroundDiv">
<img border="0" src="images/img1.jpg"
alt="iphone 5s" width="304" height="228">
</div>
<div id="sub1" style="display:none">Text to display</div>
```

Now, when they mouse over the image they will also be going over the div.  That will trigger the action that will show the inner div "sub1" that has text in it. You can also modify the text inside, etc.  The options are endless.  I hope this gets you started.  Please accept the answer if it did.  If you need more help, please post a comment and I can update my answer.  Thank you!